# Regular expression with strings separated by commas and the string 'and' at the end

Tags: python, regex

I'm fairly new to writing regular expressions and I want to write an expression that matches one or more strings of x:

```
x or x and x or x, x, and x and so on
```

Illegal examples would include:

```
xx or x, x or x and x and x
```

So far i have the expression:

```
r'^((x|\sand|\sx))+$'
```

which matches with `x` or `x and x` but im not sure how to include commas and more x's

Comment: `(a|b|c)` matches `a` or `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt matches `x` *or* `and`. But try this;

```
r'x(?:,\s*x)*\s+and\sx'
```

The trouble with an unknown number of repetitions is that you don't know how many groups there are without further analysis; so I took out the grouping parentheses (some of which were completely redundant anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this regex?

```
x(?:\s*(?:and|,)\s*x)*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/124)